# How to style label in TextField in createTheme function

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I tried to change label's margin (see the attached image to the question) from px to em/rem, but i don't know where i should write styles to structure. I can't find in MUI documentation "adjacent sibling combinator".

```
createTheme({
  MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        // props
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          // styles
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

[generated css style in inspector tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfAOi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolve it ;) I added to InputLabel this line "& + .MuiInputBase-root" to change TextField's (and another inputs) label

```
  MuiInputLabel: {
    defaultProps: {
      // props
    },
    styleOverrides: {
      root: {
        // styles
        "& +.MuiInputBase-root": {
          marginTop: '2em'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using material-ui 5:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiTextField: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& label': {
            margin: '2rem',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

https://mui.com/pt/material-ui/customization/theme-components/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that will shift the entire TextField. I'm trying to move only the label (see the attached image to the question - label+.css-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root). I edited the question, I missed it is about the label

Comment: Sorry, I edited the answer to add margin to the TextField label instead.

Comment: '& label' change style for "MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root label", but not for "label+.css-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root", here is still 16px. This style is applied on element div after label, which wrap input element.